# Javascript get text of element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get root text of element using javascript or jquery, in other words text that is in element and not in child. Javascript `innerText` return all text that is in element and childs, but i want to get parent element text only. For example see this

```
<div>
    Text1
    <div>
        Text2
    </div>
</div>
```

If i use javascript `innerText` or `textContent` it return `Text1 Text2` but i want to get only `Text1`.

How can i do this work?

Comment: I'll suggest that you don't use like this, instead write Text1 like this - `<p id="Text1">Text1</p>`. Then get the element value like this - `document.getElementById("Text1").value;`

Comment: You can see it in [iranizogam](http://iranizogam.ir)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `contents()` to get the all contents of `container` element, then use `filter()` to find the [Node.nodeType](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeType)

```js
var text = $('div#container').contents().filter(function() {
  return this.nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE
}).get(0).nodeValue;
alert(text)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='container'>
  Text1
  <div>
    Text2
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add a class='div1' or id='div2' then target that element.